# How to disable a specific JavaScript alert

Tags: firefox, javascript

On an active website I go to, there is this javascript code that is displayed on every page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){var d=document;var i=d.getElementsByTagName('iframe');if(google_ad_client!=null||(window.getComputedStyle?d.defaultView.getComputedStyle(i[i.length-1],null).getPropertyValue('display'):i[i.length-1].currentStyle['display'])=='none'){

alert('Adblock detected, please consider disabling it')

}})()
</script>
```

Is there any way that I could get my adblock -- or any other type of plugin -- to disable that specific code without disabling all javascript?

Comment: On a side note, I had disabled my adblock entirely. The script continues to display the alert. Maybe it's in the cause of my OS being a Linux Distribution..

Comment: Regardless of your comment, these links may be helpful: [1](https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=17269), [2](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/disable-anti-adblock/). Basically, there is no easy way to disable an inline script (which is in the HTML), but you can block an external script. If the code you posted is an external script, it's a duplicate of this question: http://superuser.com/q/278590/138020

Comment: You may be able to override the `alert` using a userscript (depending on when each piece is loaded in the DOM).  Something as simple as `alert = function() {};` may work.

Comment: @nerdwaller Would it be possible to use something like Stylish to edit the HTML page so that the script does nothing? Secondly, how would I write that as a userscript? I have little to none experience with javascript, but I am able to read it.

Comment: After a little more research, Userscripts are run after everything else, so that solution doesn't work.  I'm not familiar with Stylish enough to give you anything good on that, sorry!

Comment: It's alright, no worries. But, that little information is welcomed for me.

Comment: @D-Vee can you send me the website link via email? I'd like to test some theories, to see if this can be done. My email address can be found in my user profile (click my username)!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) add-on to rewrite the `alert` function:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Catch JS Alert
// @namespace   http://igalvez.net
// @include     http://*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

window.alert = function(message) {
    if(message == 'Adblock detected, please consider disabling it') {
        console.log(message);
    } else {
        confirm(message);
    }
}
```

The way this works is as follows:

If the alert box's message matches "Adblock detected, please consider disabling it", then discard it to the JS console (it will not be displayed). Otherwise, display the alert box as a `confirm` box.

Comment: Why not just keep a reference to the original `alert`?

Comment: Interesting, did not know of the `@run-at` option.  Great intel, +1.

Comment: Sorry, but that does not seem to work. o_O