# Website keeps "complaining" about my using an ad-blocker. What to do?

Tags: browser, browser-addons, website, adblock, advertisements

I'm using Ghostery and AdBlock Edge on my browser (Firefox). Some sites ask you once to maybe white-list them; and I just ignore that. But some sites (specific example: directwonen.nl when you're a registered user who wants to send messages to landlords) bring up a dialog box on every page asking again and again that I disable my adblocking...

Obviously, I do not want to turn off ad blocking. That's not only annoying but is also politically inacceptable - if some websites could get you to watch ads by annoying you when you don't, then more and more websites would adopt this approach. So - ad blocker stays on. With this constraint, however:

- What can I do to either overcome such mechanisms? or, alternatively,
- How can I make websites think I have loaded their ads despite not having done so?

For the specific case of the website I mention, here is their code:

```
var tryMessage = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!document.getElementsByClassName) return;

        var ads = document.getElementsByClassName('ads_banner'),
            ad = ads[ads.length - 1];

        if (!ad
            || ad.innerHTML.length == 0
            || ad.clientHeight === 0) {
            alert(message);
        } else {
            ad.style.display = 'none';
        }

    }, 2000);
};
```

so I guess a brute-force solution would be disabling alerts on that website.

Comment: I can use that site with no complaints about blocking ads. WIndows 7, Firefox 40 with NoScript (js blocker) and uBlock Origin (ad blocker)

Comment: @DavidPostill: It happens on some inner pages when you want to send messages to landlords.

Comment: @mdpc: The point is not to cave in to their demands, but use the website. see edit.

Comment: So it's "I want to get their service without giving back what they want"? Don't want to make it into a ethical debate, but still...

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: I actually paid for their service. But regardless, yes, if they put a website up, I want to view it without getting dialog messages popping up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Related: [How to disable a specific JavaScript alert](https://superuser.com/questions/665689/how-to-disable-a-specific-javascript-alert)

*For just addressing the alert*

- Install *Greasemonkey* and create this user script:

  ```
  // ==UserScript==
  // @name        Catch JS Alert
  // @namespace   https://directwonen.nl
  // @include     https://*
  // @version     1
  // @grant       none
  // @run-at      document-start
  // ==/UserScript==

  window.alert = function(message) {
      console.log(message);
  }
  ```

*For addressing other methods*

- If a url you need to use is blocked by the filter, you would need to add a filter exception.
- If a website has a javascript based solution. For example, "go to ad url and if that fails, delete the page." Then you could directly modify the javascript. Use [this solution](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2620135) to modify unwanted script tags. Or you could edit that solution so that it performs a regex replace of any unwanted content.

Comment: I'll try this and let you know if it works (looks like it should.)